# Flash AS2 Load Text Issue

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm trying to load some text from a URL, explode the text and then save the results to variables. Here's what my AS2 actionscript looks like:

```
// Create the empty variables
var user_title = '';
var user_message = '';
var user_author = '';

// Load the string
var loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.load("http://www.example.com/html_feed.php?md5=15d89cac6e77c8e3a592c05aee13bcb7");

// Save values to variables
loadText.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        user_title = this.thetitle;
        user_message = this.theMessage;
        user_author = this.theAuthor;
    }
};
```

And this is what the page it's trying to fetch looks like:

```
thetitle=Greetings&theMessage=Hello everyone!&theAuthor=Steve
```

When I trace the variables `user_title`, `user_message` and `user_author` I get blank outputs. This would lead me to suspect that `onLoad` part of my script isnt working.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated. AS2 and Flash Player 10 on CS5.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to trace the values? My guess is that you're tracing the values before the asynchronous load has completed. Try sticking the traces within the if conditional in your onload handler.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You know you can accept your own answer for some points?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It turns out the `crossdomain.xml` file was preventing me from accessing any other sites. The code was perfect.

This is what the file looked like. It was put in the root of my site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="requestfromthisdomain.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Hope this helps someone.